# Criar tabela mysql pelo php

Tags: mysql

Eu estou tentando criar uma tabela no banco de dados através do php mas não estou conseguindo. Aliás, mesmo utilizando o mysqli_error nenhum erro é apresentado

```
if ($new_room != "" && $new_room != " ") {
            $consulta_sala = $mysqli->query("SELECT nome_sala FROM criadas WHERE nome_sala = '".$new_room."'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta_sala) >= 1){
                echo "Essa sala já exite !";
            }else{
                $insert_1 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO criadas (nome_sala) VALUES ('$new_room')");
                $insert_2 = $mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE '$new_room' (id int(255) NOT NULL, de varchar(255) NOT NULL, para varchar(255) NOT NULL,msg varchar(400) NOT NULL,hr varchar(20) NOT NULL)") or die(mysqli_error($insert_2));
            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não se utiliza por aspas (pelo menos no MySql) no nome da tabela.
Remova as aspas que funcionará.

CREATE TABLE **NOME_TABELA**  e não **'NOME_TABELA'**

```
CREATE TABLE $new_room (id int(255) NOT NULL, de varchar(255) NOT NULL, para varchar(255) NOT NULL,msg varchar(400) NOT NULL,hr varchar(20) NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Quando eu tento utilizar o auto_increment e primary_key, ele não cria a tabela. Alguma solução ?

Comment: Provavelmente a sua sintaxe está incorreta.

Comment: Tente fazer um alter table posteriormente.